# WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.post is not a function -> Axios create then post

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, request, axios

I'm trying to make a general service for API using axios

***api.js***

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: `${window.location.origin}/`
    })  
}
```

***authenticationService.js***

```
import api from '@/services/api.js'

export default {
    login(credentials) {
        return api.post('...', credentials)
    }
  }
```

***vuex action***

```
import authenticationService from '@/services/authentication/authenticationService'

async login({commit}, credentials) {
    try {
        let response = await authenticationService.login(credentials)
        console.log(response)
    } catch(er) {
        console.log(er)
    }
})
```

**error I'm getting***

```
_services_api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.post is not a function
    at Object.login (authenticationService.js:6)
```

When I expand:

```
 login: function login(credentials) {
    return _services_api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["post"]('...', credentials);
  }
```

Looks that it doesnt import correctly api function which creates axios ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting arrow function but do not call it.
Try this:

```
import api from '@/services/api.js'

export default {
    login(credentials) {
        return api().post('...', credentials)
    }
  }
```